# Custom definition of likelihood in bayesian framework

Tags: bayesian, likelihood, genetics

I'm reading Trifinov et al. (2013) and I am trying to understand why likelihood is defined in a certain way. In particular, the definition of likelihood is given by:

> A lesion $M$ is a result of a random process with a given distribution $P^m(M)$, which specifies the probability of occurrence of the lesion $M $ due to $m$utation.
>
> [...] we define first the likelihood that a lesion $M$ is a driver lesion given that $D$ is a driver gene as
>
> $$L(M|D) \quad \underline{deff} \quad P^m(M)·δ(D ∈ M)$$
>
> where $δ(D ∈ M)$ is $1$ if the lesion $M$ includes the gene $D$ and $0$ otherwise

This is defined as the likelihood, i.e. the probability of data under the hypothesis. However, I am unable to map the definition of likelihood to the actual problem, i.e. the lesion $M$ is a driver lesion given that $D$ is a driver gene.

If I understood correctly the definition, there would be no need for the first term of the definition, i.e. $P^m(M)$, since the indicator function will suffice. This because, if $D$ is in $M$, the $M$ lesion is a driver lesion, $0$ otherwise.

Could you point me to a way, or a reading, to understand how to map the definition and to understand if the actual definition captures the hypothesis it wants to test?

- Trifonov, Vladimir, et al. "[MutComFocal: an integrative approach to identifying recurrent and focal genomic alterations in tumor samples.](https://bmcsystbiol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1752-0509-7-25)" BMC systems biology 7.1 (2013): 25.

Comment: This language, lesion, driver, gene, makes it difficult to understand for simple statisticians. But any way... is the following logical? $$ L(M|D) = P(M|D) = P(M) \cdot \delta(D \in M) $$ and could you explain why if not? They seem to use likelihood as probability *"the likelihood that a lesion M is a driver lesion given that D is a driver gene"*

Comment: @MartijnWeterings The lesion is a set of genes. Driver gene in this case indicates that the gene is critical, and therefore the set of genes (lesion) which contains it is critical. It does not make sense to me why the likelihood that lesion M (set of genes) is a driver is not equal to the indicator function $\delta(D \in M)$, since: if the driver gene is in $M$, $P(M) = 1$, otherwise $0$.

Comment: I just read the source and it is very difficult to follow.  ----- The (bad) discussions I get with my other half, who is molecular biologist, when I ask her to explain 'what is a gene?' or 'what is an allele?' make me remember that I better not mingle in these type of questions.  ----- You can ignore my earlier comment. Somehow they do speak instead about the L(M|D) = P(D|M) but it is very unclear for outsiders.

Comment: The article defines L(M|D) but it is used nowhere. They define it "to obtain the posteriors" and those posteriors seem to be fine (and do not use those Likelihood definitions). So you might just ignore their likelihood stuff. $$P(D|M) =P(M|D) \frac{P(D)}{P(M)}$$ with $P(M|D) = \delta (D \in M)$ and $P(M) = \sum_{G \in M} P(G)$.